# SQL Return ALL Results ALL, Distinct?

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

PROBLEM: Need the query to return the MONTH_NAME and YIELD for b.Monthly_Yield even when the Month_Name is NOT found in a.Month.  For some reason, if the Month is not found in a.Month, even when I add to the selection b.month, the query still will not return the b.Monthly_Yield value.  The way I have it now, if the MONTH is NOT found in table "a" but the month is found in table "b" the result will NOT return.  I need the result to return for "b" even if that month is not found in "a".

Note: "Month" is the Month Number

DATA RESULTS WITH LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
Month  Month_Name  Yield_1  Yield_0
------------------------------------
2      Febrero     11.44    14
3      Marzo       NULL     3.21
4      Abril       NULL     14.24
7      Julio       NULL     10.36
8      Agosto      NULL     0
9      Septiembre  NULL     -9.6
10     Octubre     NULL     10.35
11     Noviembre   NULL     1.4
12     Diciembre   11.44    -1.18
```

DATA RESULTS WITH RIGHT OUTER JOIN:

```
Month  Month_Name  Yield_1  Yield_0
------------------------------------
NULL   NULL        11.44    NULL
2      Febrero     11.44    14
12     Diciembre   11.44    -1.18
```

Query:

```
SET @ID_CARTERA = 8;

select     
    a.Month,
    a.Month_Name,
    a.Monthly_Yield,
    b.Monthly_Yield

from
( select  
      RIGHT(A.F_ANOMES, 2) Month,
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOMES, 2)=01,'Enero',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOMES, 2)=02,'Febrero',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOMES, 2)=03,'Marzo',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOMES, 2)=04,'Abril',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOMES, 2)=05,'Mayo',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOMES, 2)=06,'Junio',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOMES, 2)=07,'Julio',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOMES, 2)=08,'Agosto',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOMES, 2)=09,'Septiembre',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOMES, 2)=10,'Octubre',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOMES, 2)=11,'Noviembre',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOMES, 2)=12,'Diciembre',
      '')
      ))))))))))) Month_Name,

      ROUND(A.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Monthly_Yield

from      dr_rent_carteras_meses A
where     A.ID_CARTERA = @ID_CARTERA
And       A.IND_RENTABILIDAD = 1
And       LEFT(A.F_ANOMES, 4) = ( select MAX(left(F_ANOMES, 4 ) ) - 0
                                  from dr_rent_carteras_meses
                                  where ID_CARTERA = @ID_CARTERA ) ) a

left outer join 
    ( select  
      RIGHT(A.F_ANOMES, 2) Month,
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOMES, 2)=01,'Enero',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOMES, 2)=02,'Febrero',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOMES, 2)=03,'Marzo',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOMES, 2)=04,'Abril',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOMES, 2)=05,'Mayo',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOMES, 2)=06,'Junio',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOMES, 2)=07,'Julio',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOMES, 2)=08,'Agosto',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOMES, 2)=09,'Septiembre',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOMES, 2)=10,'Octubre',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOMES, 2)=11,'Noviembre',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOMES, 2)=12,'Diciembre',
      '')
      ))))))))))) Month_Name,

      ROUND(A.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Monthly_Yield

from      dr_rent_carteras_meses A
where     A.ID_CARTERA = @ID_CARTERA
And       A.IND_RENTABILIDAD = 1
And       LEFT(A.F_ANOMES, 4) = ( select MAX(left(F_ANOMES, 4 ) ) - 1
                                  from dr_rent_carteras_meses
                                  where ID_CARTERA = @ID_CARTERA ) ) b on ( a.Month = b.Month )
```

Comment: ... Are your dates stored as a character type?  If so, please change them to an actual date type.  Otherwise, please use the appropriate functions for your database.  What RDBMS (SQL Server?)?  Why are you using `LEFT(F_ANOMES, 4)`, then subtracting 1 from it - is it character or numeric?  You probably also want a calendar file (from which you could select the first day of the month).

Comment: It's a bit unclear. Maybe it's just me, but if you can, please add an example to your post to illustrate the problem: what the query actually returns and what it *should* return.

Comment: Yes, dates are stored as DATE.  As you can see in the query, I am SELECTING the Month Number from the date. LEFT(F_ANOMES, 4) identifies the YEAR Value.  Subtracting 1 from the Year's MAX value returns the PRIOR YEAR's data results in the next consecutive column.

Comment: I'm not sure what DBMS this is, but does it have some construct like a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) in it? That would make your query a lot more readable.

Comment: It's MySQL.  The Database is in Spanish, but I'm using English Aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change LEFT OUTER JOIN to RIGHT OUTER JOIN.

@ypercube is correct.  Use FULL OUTER JOIN.

The reason why you are not getting the month name is that there is now value in the a table.  So you need to get it from the b table.

Try

```
ISNULL(a.Month, b.Month) as Month
ISNULL(a.Month_Name, b.Month_Name) as Month
```

Also, please take the advice of the comments.  Use the correct data type functions.  Also look into CASE statements.

You also might want to query all the info in the join and then do the data conversion (month name) on the outside query.  that way you don't have to do it twice.

Comment: Changing to RIGHT OUTER JOIN now returns the DATA cell for b.monthly_yield but EXCLUDES 1) several results for a.monthly_yield, and 2) does not return the Month name

Comment: I posted the DATA Results I get with LEFT OUTER JOIN and what returns with RIGHT OUTER JOIN

Comment: if `LEFT` and `RIGHT` fail, try `FULL JOIN`